# angularjs performance best practices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coding-style

I take a style based on [johnpapa style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide), and 
according to Miško presentation on [Angularjs MTV meetup Best Practices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY) at 49:44

#### he say that performance depend on 2 thing :

> 1. How many binding you have.
> 2. How expensive you getter. (should fast)

And i think that means simple and fast. In my comprehension getter mean a method in a service. But in my case a little bit complex.
So how make it simple? i guest it's not possible to change the algorithm? or just calling internal (private) function in a service? does it take effect?

#### So here is my question :

> 1. Best practice to make getter on a method in service so will not cause memory leak.
>
> > I hope somebody can make an clear axample with the explanation
> >
> > How IIFE work ?
> >
> > > Can somebody explain it to me?
> > >
> > > How IIFE work on a function inside factory (method in service)?
> > >
> > > > Is it remove the global variable too? even if i use var, like when we return a factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question (or rather multiple questions) is rather broad. And you are conflating and combining multiple concepts here, but I will try to untangle you.

**First**, IIFE. This has nothing to do with Angular performance. IIFE is a way to namespace your global scope. So, instead of exposing functions on the global scope that could result in a conflict, the best practice is to use IIFE.

```
var globalObj =
    (function(){
      var privateVar = 5;
      function doPrivateFn(x, y){}

      return {
        publicFn: function(x){ doPrivateFn(x, privateVar) };
      }
    })();
```

Now, the only thing exposed is to the global scope is `globalObj`, which has `globalObj.publicFn()`.

**Second**, IIFE are sometimes used when registering services or controllers with Angular instead of inline anonymous function: `.factory("MySvc", function(){})`:

```
(function(){
  angular.factory("MySvc", MySvcFactory);

  function MySvcFactory($http){
    // ...
  }
})();
```

All this does is hides the `MySvc` factory function `MySvcFactory` from the global scope.

**Finally**, the point about making getters fast is not about memory leak, but rather computational intensity of the getter function.

So, if you have a binding in a expression, like this:

```
<span>{{getCount()}}</span>
```

or this:

```
<div ng-show="isShown(item)">{{item.prop}}</div>
```

The idea is to make these functions very fast, if not just a getter:

```
$scope.isShown = function(item){
  return (item.a || item.b) && $scope.somethingElse;
}
```

And never do things like this:

```
<div ng-show="isUnique(item)">{{item}}</div>
```

where `isUnique` perfoms a for loop search:

```
$scope.isUnique = function(item){
   for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
     if (item === list[i]) return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

because this function will run on every digest cycle, and sometime even multiple times. Instead, calculate uniqueness and cache the result somewhere, so that you could just return it.